# JQuery: SlideUp a div that is within a hidden parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

I have a page with buttons that show/hide divs using slideUp() and slideDown(). Previously I was just using hide() and show() to display and hide these divs, but I really want to use the slide animations because it helps the user see what's changing on the page.

Here's the problem: Some of these divs exist within other divs that are also hidden at times, and it seems that **when the parent div is hidden, slideUp() will not work on the child.**

Here's a rough example:

```js
$('#Abutton').unbind('click').click(function(){
   $('.A').slideToggle(500);
   });

$('#Cbutton').unbind('click').click(function(){
   $('.C').slideToggle(500);
   });

$('#Bbutton').unbind('click').click(function(){
   $('.B').slideToggle(500);
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Abutton">Toggle A</button>
<button id='Bbutton'>Toggle B</button>
<button id='Cbutton'>Toggle C</button>

<div class='context1'>
  <div class="A">
      <p>Parent</p>
      <div class='C'>
      <p> and child </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='context2'>
  <div class="B">
     <p> something else </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, if the user toggles OFF "A," then toggles OFF "C," C doesn't successfully hide because it's within a hidden parent - so when the user toggles A back on, C will be displayed even though the user just turned it off. It seems that it's not hiding successfully because the animation effect can't execute when it's invisible (?).

Again, when I replace the toggle functions with show() and hide(), it works just fine, but I really need the animating effect.

The only solution I could find was to use setTimeout to do the following after slideUp finishes...

```
$('.C').slideUp(500);
        setTimeout(function(){ $('.C').hide() }, 500);
```

...but I was wondering if anyone out there knew of a simpler solution. Thanks in advance for any insight you might share!

EDIT: I realize this is a bit difficult to explain and I probably didn't do a very good job explaining myself; here's what I want to happen sequentially:

1. The user turns off A. In this one instance, A contains C, so both are hidden, but there may be other instances where C is not the child.
2. The user turns off C.
3. When A is turned back on, C is off.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this:

```js
  $('#Abutton').click(function(){
    if($('.A').is(':visible')){
        if($('.C').is(':visible')){
             $('.C').slideUp(500,function(){
                 $('.A').slideUp(500);
             });
         }else{
             $('.A').slideUp(500);
         }
     }else{
         $('.A').slideDown(500,function(){
             $('.C').slideDown(500);
         });
     }

    
  });

  $('#Cbutton').click(function(){
  if($('.A').is(':visible')){
      $('.C').slideToggle(500);
  }else{
              $('.A').slideDown(500,function(){
                     $('.C').slideDown(500);
              });
  }


  });

    $('#Bbutton').click(function(){
   $('.B').slideToggle(500);
 });
```

```css
     div{
      margin: 10px;
      border-style:solid;
      border-width:1px;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="Abutton">Toggle A</button>
<button id='Bbutton'>Toggle B</button>
<button id='Cbutton'>Toggle C</button>


<div class='context1'>
  <div class="A">
      <p>Parent</p>
      <div class='C'>
      <p> and child </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='context2'>
  <div class="B">
     <p> something else </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the work you put into this. Unfortunately, this does not solve the issue.I need this to happen 1. user clicks Toggle A and hides ".A" which is the parent of "C." 2. User clicks Toggle C. Nothing displays because its parent is hidden. 3. User clicks toggle A again and .C is hidden because the user just toggled it off.

Answer (score 0):

There is callback function, that trigger when your animation is ended

```
var $c =  $('.C');
$c.slideUp(500, function(){
  $c.hide(
});
```

Comment: Hello! I tried the callback function originally, but it seems that (on my page) it executes the hide function before the slideUp animation. Any idea why?